# Imprimir lista de dados json

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

preciso pegar os dados de um arquivo json e com esses dados gerar uma lista correspondente a categoria que ele pertence por exemplo se é da categoria tecnologia preciso gerar uma lista de todos os itens que sejam dessa categoria, se for da categoria de pesquisa a mesma coisa e assim por diante, e para filtrar do mesmo jeito os demais campos, vou colocar como está estruturado o meu json, e como comecei a desenvolver o código, mas ta dando erro, e json não é o meu forte, se puderem me ajudar agradeço

```
var json = [
  {
        "ID":"1",
        "TÍTULO":"Pesquisa tal...",
        "TIPO":"Pesquisa",
        "CATEGORIA":"Pesquisa",        
        "AUTORES":[
              {
                    "AUTOR":"Fulano da Silva",
                    "INSTITUIÇÃO":"Faculdade tal"
              },
              {
                    "AUTOR":"x da Silva",
                    "INSTITUIÇÃO":"Escola"
              }
        ]
  },
  {
        "ID":"2",
        "TÍTULO":"Tecnologia",
        "TIPO":"Tecnologia",        
        "CATEGORIA":"Tecnologia",
        "AUTORES":[
              {
                    "AUTOR":"y",
                    "INSTITUIÇÃO":"aaa"
              },
              {
                    "AUTOR":"Z",
                    "INSTITUIÇÃO":"SASASA"
              }
        ]
  },
{
        "ID":"3",
        "TÍTULO":"Pesquisa tal...",
        "TIPO":"Pesquisa",
        "CATEGORIA":"Pesquisa",        
        "AUTORES":[
              {
                    "AUTOR":"Fulano da Silva",
                    "INSTITUIÇÃO":"Faculdade tal"
              },
              {
                    "AUTOR":"x da Silva",
                    "INSTITUIÇÃO":"Escola"
              }
        ]
  },
{
        "ID":"4",
        "TÍTULO":"Tecnologia",
        "TIPO":"Tecnologia",        
        "CATEGORIA":"Tecnologia",
        "AUTORES":[
              {
                    "AUTOR":"y",
                    "INSTITUIÇÃO":"aaa"
              },
              {
                    "AUTOR":"Z",
                    "INSTITUIÇÃO":"SASASA"
              }
        ]
  }
]

for(var i=0;i< json.length; i++){
 var html = "<tr>";
 html +="<td>"+json[i].ID+"</td>";
 html +="<td>"+json[i].TÍTULO+"</td>";
 html +="<td>"+json[i].TIPO+"</td>";
 html +="<td>"+json[i].NATUREZA DO TRABALHO+"</td>";
 html +="</tr>";
 $('table tbody').append(html);
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito que o que você está procurando é o método `filter`, com ele você pode filtrar seu array de objetos pelo valor de uma das propriedade dos seus objetos.

Segue um exemplo do `filter` sendo usado na sua variável JSON exibindo no console só os objetos com propriedade CATEGORIA com valor igual "Pesquisa".

```js
var json = [
  {
        "ID":"1",
        "TÍTULO":"Pesquisa tal...",
        "TIPO":"Pesquisa",
        "CATEGORIA":"Pesquisa",        
        "AUTORES":[
              {
                    "AUTOR":"Fulano da Silva",
                    "INSTITUIÇÃO":"Faculdade tal"
              },
              {
                    "AUTOR":"x da Silva",
                    "INSTITUIÇÃO":"Escola"
              }
        ]
  },
  {
        "ID":"2",
        "TÍTULO":"Tecnologia",
        "TIPO":"Tecnologia",        
        "CATEGORIA":"Tecnologia",
        "AUTORES":[
              {
                    "AUTOR":"y",
                    "INSTITUIÇÃO":"aaa"
              },
              {
                    "AUTOR":"Z",
                    "INSTITUIÇÃO":"SASASA"
              }
        ]
  },
{
        "ID":"3",
        "TÍTULO":"Pesquisa tal...",
        "TIPO":"Pesquisa",
        "CATEGORIA":"Pesquisa",        
        "AUTORES":[
              {
                    "AUTOR":"Fulano da Silva",
                    "INSTITUIÇÃO":"Faculdade tal"
              },
              {
                    "AUTOR":"x da Silva",
                    "INSTITUIÇÃO":"Escola"
              }
        ]
  },
{
        "ID":"4",
        "TÍTULO":"Tecnologia",
        "TIPO":"Tecnologia",        
        "CATEGORIA":"Tecnologia",
        "AUTORES":[
              {
                    "AUTOR":"y",
                    "INSTITUIÇÃO":"aaa"
              },
              {
                    "AUTOR":"Z",
                    "INSTITUIÇÃO":"SASASA"
              }
        ]
  }
]

console.log("Pesquisa");
console.log(json.filter(x => x.CATEGORIA == "Pesquisa"));
//Aperte o botão Executar e abra seu console do browser com F12 para visualizar o JSON filtrado
//no seu console, com um array que só exibe os objetos com CATEGORIA de valor igual a "Pesquisa"
```